# I want to write the ternary operator equivalent of the following if condition

Tags: if-statement

```
String destinationFile = request.getParameter("destinationFile ");
if (destinationFile == null || "".equals(destinationFile))
 response.sendRedirect("/astro/login/index.jsp?destinationFile =customerLogin.jsp");
```

I have written it as

```
String destinationFile = request.getParameter("destinationFile ");
response.sendRedirect((destinationFile==null || "".equals(destinationFile)) ? "/astro/login/index.jsp?destinationFile =customerLogin.jsp" : destinationFile);
```

the problem with terinary operator is that what should be placed after :

In if condition i have not mentioned any else. I have to verify the directory structure should be pre-pended to destinatedFile.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot do that.

The ternary operator produces an expression which can be used e. g. as function argument.

That said, you could use the terary operator if you had an `else` branch which would send something as well.

So

```
if (a) {
    response.sendRedirect(b);
} else {
    response.sendRedirect(c);
}
```

could be rewritten as

```
response.sendRedirect(a ? b : c);
```

but if your `else` branch does something completely else (or nothing at all, as in your case), you are stuck with the normal `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

using ternary operator--->

```
var reult =
    (request.getParameter("destinationFile").ToString() != String.Empty || request.getParameter("destinationFile") != null) ? response.sendRedirect("/astro/login/index.jsp?destinationFile =customerLogin.jsp") :
    null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that...
A terniary operator implicates a IF-ELSE condition, and you only have the IF part.

For instance, suppose you have this code:

```
String destinationFile = request.getParameter("destinationFile ");
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(destinationFile))
    response.sendRedirect(destinationFile);
else
    response.sendRedirect("/astro/login/index.jsp?destinationFile=customerLogin.jsp");
```

then you can change it to:

```
String destinationFile = request.getParameter("destinationFile ");
response.sendRedirect(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(destinationFile) ? destinationFile : "/astro/login/index.jsp?destinationFile=customerLogin.jsp"));
```